# Matching columns from 2 tables

Tags: powerbi

I have 2 data in Power BI- Table and Table 2.

I would like to know how can I achieve Table 3 from Table 1 and Table 2.

[image: [Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mxut2.png)]

[image]

[image]

Thanks !

Tried using text.contains to search, but its taking too long.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of data. Paste data as copiable text.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [take a tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)!

Comment: If you are interested in Power Query (Transform), you can do sequential joins of Table1 with Table2[Country] and Table2[City] followed by a little clean-up. Not sure which would be more efficient.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Add 2 calculated colmuns to your Table:

```
City = RELATED('Table 2'[City])
```

```
Country = 
IF(
    'Table'[City] = BLANK(), 
    'Table'[Location], 
    RELATED('Table 2'[Country])
)
```

The resulting Table will look like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this answer. However, the table will not show the Country for Joseph and Lazarus; I would like the table to show their Country with the City left blank.

Comment: I see. Just updated my answer.